# Present Perfect and Past Perfect with before and after

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect

I don't quite understand how present perfect and past perfect work with before and after. Could you explain that to me?

For example:

1. I'll telephone you before I come - I'll telephone you before I've come
2. We can't leave before the speeches finish - We can't leave before the speeches have finished
3. I usually go straight home after I finish work - I usually go straight home after I've finished work
4. After Lara finished school, she went to America - After Lara had finished school, she went to America
5. He went out before I finished my sentence - He went out before I had finished my sentence

Do those pairs have similar meaning? Do Past Perfect refer to the past (examples: 4 and 5) and Present Perfect refer to the future (examples: 1, 2) or to the present (examples: 3)?

Comment: In all cases except the first, both tenses are possible. _I'll telephone you before I've come_ is definitely unidiomatic, though it's hard to explain why.